# How i can make simultaneous http request in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to make http request for each element of my produtosConfirmadosAnuncio array.

I'm trying to do with `for()` but sometimes this don't work, my browser stop works (I'm testing with two elements in for).

I try this way:

```
for(let i=0;i<this.produtosConfirmadosAnuncio.length;i++){
    this.marketplaceService.anunciar(this.produtosConfirmadosAnuncio[i])

.pipe(
        take(1)
    )
    .subscribe((res) => {

        this.submited = false;

        for (let c = 0; c < this.produtosConfirmadosAnuncio.length; c++) {
            if (this.produtosConfirmadosAnuncio[c].id == this.produtosConfirmadosAnuncio[i].id) {
                this.produtosConfirmadosAnuncio.splice(c, 1)
            }
            c--;
        } //Remove the element when requisition return success


        this.valorAtualProgress += this.quantidadeSomarProgress; //sum progress bar


        if (this.valorAtualProgress == 100) { //close the progress bar when value is 100
            this.toastrService.showToast(true, "Pronto!", res.mensagem);
        }

    }, (err) => {
        this.loadingprogress = false
        if (err.status == 401) {
            this.authService.Logout();
        }
    })
}
```

There's other way to do this? maybe wait the first requisition response to continue?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the RxJS `forkJoin` operator for this. The `forkJoin` operator will subscribe and run each Observable, gathering up each value emitted and finally emitting a single array value containing all the completed HTTP requests.

> This operator is similar to `Promise.all` and will wait for all observables to complete before returning the results.

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';

const requests = this.produtosConfirmadosAnuncio.map(p => {
    return this.marketplaceService.anunciar(p).pipe(take(1));
});

forkJoin(requests).subscribe(results => {
    // use results[0] for the first call
    //     results[1] for the second one ...
    ...
});
```

Here is the [RxJS doc](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) about the operator. Here is an [article](https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/performing-multiple-http-requests-in-angular-4-5-with-forkjoin-74f3ac166d61) showing its use to make multiple HTTP requests simultaneously.

Comment: forkJoin waits for all requests to complete, which might not be what OP wanted

Comment: This help but is not exactly what i want, this way i don't have access of actual requisition, i will lose my progress bar. I do no why in Network browser tab i can see the requisition is duplicated